# Where does the money come from?

Tags: tournament, tournament-directors

I prefer watching top players' games. Recently, the Silver Lake Open has ended and now Serbia Open Masters is going on. So my question is, who pays for the travelling and accommodation costs of players? Is it the organiser, the players themselves or their country's government who covers these costs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For invitationals generally the organizers will pay (or the invited players won't accept the invitation). For open tournaments it's a different matter, and the players themselves pay.

An event like "Serbia open masters" might be funded by Serbia's chess organization, though (I have not checked).

Answer (score 6):

All three.

For top players, it's the organizer who foots the bill just to get the name value.  For some countries, they'll pay for their players to travel to a well-known tournament to show the "greatness" of their country.  The less famous tournaments couldn't afford a top 20 GM, but have been known to "bribe" lower GMs, hoping other GMs will join at their own expense.

I don't have the knowledge, but I assume that title tournaments, eg. World Championship, that FIDE   pays the expenses as it keeps all the profits.